# Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException: ''System.__ComObject' does not contain a definition for 'Language''

Tags: c#, calculator

Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException: ''System.__ComObject' does not contain a definition for 'Language''

Does anyone know why I'm always getting this error? I found this code on a youtube video to make a calculator. Pleas help.

```
private void result_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        result.Background = Brushes.BlueViolet;


        Type scriptType = Type.GetTypeFromCLSID(Guid.Parse("0E59F1D5-1FBE-11D0-8FF2-00A0D10038BC"));
        dynamic obj = Activator.CreateInstance(scriptType, false);
        obj.Language = "javascript";
        string str = null;

        try
        {
            var res = obj.Eval(screen.Text);
            str = Convert.ToString(res);
            screen.Text = screen.Text + "=" + str;
        }
        catch (SystemException)
        {

            screen.Text = "syntax error";
        }
```

Comment: Project > Add COM reference > tick "Microsoft Script Control 1.0".  Initialize with var obj = new MSScriptControl.ScriptControl();

Answer (score 0):

Might be you are hitting this issue: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/13274

> Thanks for reporting this issue. Support for usage of the dynamic keyword with COM objects wasn't done for .NET Core 3.0. This issue is being track in https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/issues/24246 for .Net 5. The work around is to cast the class to the corresponding interface.

Just make sure there is a language definition in the com object and the corresponding interface.