# Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel ''System.__ComObject' does not contain a definition for 'Value''

Tags: c#, excel, visual-studio, office-interop, office-automation

Just trying to get this to work at all.

In my .csproj:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <COMReference Include="Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel">
        <WrapperTool>tlbimp</WrapperTool>
        <VersionMinor>9</VersionMinor>
        <VersionMajor>1</VersionMajor>
        <Guid>00020813-0000-0000-c000-000000000046</Guid>
        <Lcid>0</Lcid>
        <Isolated>false</Isolated>
        <EmbedInteropTypes>true</EmbedInteropTypes>
    </COMReference>
</ItemGroup>
```

Code:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
        Application excel = new Application();
        Workbook wb = excel.Workbooks.Open(path);
        Worksheet excelSheet = wb.ActiveSheet;

        //Read the first cell
        string test = excelSheet.Cells[1, 1].Value.ToString();

        Console.WriteLine(test);
}
```

string test = excelSheet.Cells[1, 1].Value.ToString(); throws:

```
Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException: ''System.__ComObject' does not contain a definition for 'Value''
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69697910/microsoft-csharp-runtimebinder-runtimebinderexception-system-comobject-doe

Comment: Thanks for posting that. I can't get it to work by changing it to casting, but I changed from .NET Core to .NET Framework and it works. I wish anyone trying to get this to work in .NET Core a lot of luck, they are going to need it

Comment: Just keep your VS version updated, this is only a problem with a very old version of .NETCore.